# Where to download pywin64?

Tags: python, pywin

Now,I use windows7 professional,the version of python is 2.7.6,I need a editor to write code.
does pywin have 64bits?And where to download?thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no `pywin64`. But `pywin32` has 64-bit builds.

See `pywin32-219.win-amd64-py2.7.exe` at the [official site repository](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/)

Comment: thanks a lot.I solve the trouble.but I don't find the running file under c:\Python27,can you tell me?